# Uncaught Reference Javascript Error when submitting data via html to contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, javascript

I created a contract (Freight) using the `"ratings"` tutorial template. The Freight contract is meant to store values entered in the html page (`input.html`) and submitted. Just like the "ratings" tutorial, though at the moment i get

```
JavaScript  error   12:49:31    input.html - line 99 - Uncaught ReferenceError: setFreight is not defined
```

whenever I hit the submit button. How do I solve this?

Link to git repository: https://github.com/Akiiki/Freight.git

Answer (score 3):

Couple of things :

-This wont return / do nothing :

```
function setFreight(string contNumber,
             string s_Invoice,
            string c_Invoice,
            string s_number,
            uint t_Weight,
            uint t_Quantity) {

}
```

-I don't see where you are requiring web3.js ? You need will need it.

-Where are you instantiating your contract , where is the contract abi ? Where is the contract address ? is your RCP node proprelly configured ?

I feel like your missing this part. so here it is :

Try this :

First inside your browser console deploy  using this code :

```
var freightContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"contNumber","type":"string"},{"name":"s_Invoice","type":"string"},{"name":"c_Invoice","type":"string"},{"name":"s_number","type":"string"},{"name":"t_Weight","type":"uint256"},{"name":"t_Quantity","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setFreight","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"contNumber","type":"string"},{"name":"s_Invoice","type":"string"},{"name":"c_Invoice","type":"string"},{"name":"s_number","type":"string"},{"name":"t_Weight","type":"uint256"},{"name":"t_Quantity","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getFreight","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"type":"constructor"}]);
var freight = freightContract.new(
   {
     from: web3.eth.accounts[0], 
     data: '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', 
     gas: 3000000
   }, function(e, contract){
    console.log(e, contract);
    if (typeof contract.address != 'undefined') {
         console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
    }
 })
```

Then get the return contract address and in the same console do :

```
var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(freightContract.abi);
var param1 = "xx"
var parm2 = 2
MyContract.setFreight.call(param1,param2) or . sendTransaction(param1,param2,{from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas:3000000})
```

in case you actually doing a transaction and not only reading data.

This should work.

Finally once your contract is deploy once you can access it again using :

```
var freightContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"contNumber","type":"string"},{"name":"s_Invoice","type":"string"},{"name":"c_Invoice","type":"string"},{"name":"s_number","type":"string"},{"name":"t_Weight","type":"uint256"},{"name":"t_Quantity","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setFreight","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"contNumber","type":"string"},{"name":"s_Invoice","type":"string"},{"name":"c_Invoice","type":"string"},{"name":"s_number","type":"string"},{"name":"t_Weight","type":"uint256"},{"name":"t_Quantity","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getFreight","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"type":"constructor"}]);
```

and Then

```
MyContract.at("your contract address");
```